# how to logout from a page using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have made an login page using angularJS, in which I give username and password static, upon submitting the my form it is redirected to a welcome screen, now I want to logout upon clicking logout , to logout from the welcome page and return to login page? how is it possible using angularJS?

here is the code I wrote :

```
.controller("loginController", function($scope, $location, $rootScope){
                            $scope.login = function() {
                                var user = $scope.username;
                                var password = $scope.password;
                                var result = $scope.username + $scope.password;
                                console.log(result);
                                if (user == "admin" && password == 'admin'){
                                    $rootScope.loggedIn = true;
                                    $location.path('/welcome');
                                } else {
                                    alert("INVALID CREDENTIALS");
                                }
                            }
.controller('welcomeController', function($scope){
                    $scope.message = "welcome here"
                })
```

Comment: I have also stored user and password in a variable, but don't know how it will work!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write a function to redirect your page to the home page and do this,

```
.controller('logoutController', function($scope,$location){
  $scope.logout = function(){
      $location.path('/home');
  }
})
```

and call it using ng-click

```
<button ng-click="logout()">
  Logout
</button>
```

Comment: What you have done here is redirected it back to home page, but if i change the url like http://localhost/login/#/ to http://localhost/login/#/welcome then it is redirecting me again to the welcome page which in this case shall not occur, if I am not logged in!! Using this way this approach is working which is wrong, there must be some condition needed to put !!

Comment: You should check if the user is authenticated inside the routes

Comment: mistakingly sir

Answer (score 5):

Do as told by [Sajeetharan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1749403/sajeetharan) in previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43360620/3395365). 
Just clear values of `$scope.username` and `$scope.password` in logout function

Write a function to redirect your page to the home page and do this,

```
.controller('logoutController', function($scope,$location){
  $scope.logout = function(){
      //Just clear values from scope
      $scope.username = '';
      $scope.password = '';
      $location.path('/home');
  }
})
```

and call it using ng-click

```
<button ng-click="logout()">
  Logout
</button>
```

***By the way, the approach you are using is not very good.***

Comment: currently I am using static input values because I am a beginner to AngularJS, my problem is not the values I need my home page not to redirect at welcome screen until unless the user logs in. In my case if I change the url localhost/login/# to localhost/login/#/welcome like this, then it is redirecting to this page, regardless the fact that I am loggedIn or not!

Comment: You have to create a **validation** function in controller or a service(_better option_) which you have to call on load of any controller(_running that function should be first think done in controller_). In that function you have to check if user is authorized to access current page or not and take action accordingly.